# isLoading na requisição não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, html, react

estou tentando colocar um isLoading na minha aplicação feita com react mas não está funcionando, eu tenho a minha função handleSearch que está fazendo a requisição, esta função está sendo passada para o meu componente que distribui os dados via props para todos os outros componentes até chegar no meu componente de busca que recebe essa função, eu tentei colocar o isLoading mas não está dando certo, ele realiza a requisição e dps entra no meu `setInterval()` más ele nao seta o isLoading como false, mostrando o setInterval infinitamente.
Minha função que faz a requisição

```
handleSearch = e => {
const value = e.target.value;
const keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
const ENTER = 13;

if (keyCode === ENTER) {
  setInterval(() => {
  console.log('ENTREI AQUI')
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  }, 1000); 
  axios
    //fazendo a requisição para a API usando a funçao getApiGitHubURL
    .get(this.getApiGitHubURL(value))
    .then(result => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false, 
        userinfo: {
          username: result.data.name,
          photo: result.data.avatar_url,
          login: result.data.login,
          repos: result.data.public_repos,
          followers: result.data.followers,
          following: result.data.following
        },
        repos: [],
        starred: []
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("ERRO: ", err);
      return <h1>Ops, deu algo errado !</h1>;
    });
}
```

};

Meu componente que recebe a função `handleSearch` via props

```
import React from "react";

function Search({ handleSearch }) {
  return (
    <div className="search">
      <input 
        type="search"
        onKeyUp={handleSearch}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

Obs: já tentei passar para frente o isLoading até chegar no meu componente de busca más acho que estou fazendo alguma coisa de errado pq não funcionou, se puderem me ajudar ficarei grato, obrigado !

[image: console.log() colocado no setInterval]

Comment: Não está fazendo o efeito essa é sua duvida? (porque se for seu código está errado mesmo)

Comment: Ele não está dando o delay no isLoading q eu programei pra ele fazer antes de realizar a requisição usando o setInterval

Comment: Teste o exemplo que eu te mandei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não utilize dando um `delay` utilize assim quando o `dom` for atualizado pelo novo valor em `isLoading`, executa a rotina do serviço que também dá um tempo e depois quando acabar essa requisição muda novamente o valor de `isLoading`, exemplo:

```
handleSearch = e => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    const ENTER = 13;
    if (keyCode === ENTER) {            
        this.setState({ isLoading: true }, () => {
            axios               
                .get(this.getApiGitHubURL(value))
                .then(result => {
                  this.setState({
                    isLoading: false, 
                    userinfo: {
                      username: result.data.name,
                      photo: result.data.avatar_url,
                      login: result.data.login,
                      repos: result.data.public_repos,
                      followers: result.data.followers,
                      following: result.data.following
                    },
                    repos: [],
                    starred: []
                  });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.log("ERRO: ", err);
                  return <h1>Ops, deu algo errado !</h1>;
                });
        });
    }
};
```

Dentro do `this.setState` pode ser passado uma segunda função para quando acabar a atualização do `setState` seja executado logo após essa função. Esse `delay` é melhor ele produz um valor real de cada operação.

Comment: entao, esse realmente parece ser um bom modo de fazer isso mas eu queria simular a requisição aplicando um delay durante o processo, mas isso n foi possível com o setInterval, acho que minha pergunta ficou um pouco confusa

Comment: @GiovanniManganotti você não está complicando, pra que colocar um `delay` a mais? já que tem o `delay` natural. Se ainda quiser colocar um `delay` para aumentar é só colocar um setTimeout dentro da função que eu falei ... simples assim.

Comment: ok, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @GiovanniManganotti tem mais alguma duvida? se não é a resposta da sua pergunta?

Comment: eu consegui usar o setInterval, fiz como vc disse e deu certo, obrigado era apenas essa a minha duvida, colocar um delay para simular uma requisição na aplicação